# Call a jquery function after dom changed with an event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery `clickno` class generated after a click event. It is a class in popover generated after a click event.

```
$(".clickno").on('click', function(){$(this).parent().parent().parent().hide()})
```

So when I add this to my scripts, it is not working because there is no `clickno` class when DOM loaded. How can i call this function after the popover loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delegate the event to parent of `.clickno` if you know it parent or delegating the event to document could also do that for you.

```
$(document).on('click', ".clickno", function()
    {$(this).parent().parent().parent().hide()
});
```

#### Delegated events

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers,
>   [reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

Move this

```
$(".clickno").on('click', function(){$(this).parent().parent().parent().hide()})
```

inside the click event code of the element on which the popover is loaded.

Eg:

```
$(".button_that_loads_popover").on('click',function({
 // Pop-over loaded
 $(".clickno").on('click', function(){$(this).parent().parent().parent().hide()});
}));
```