# How to detect which button is clicked in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have code like this :

```
@foreach(....)
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <!-- content --!>
        <button class="btn btn-success btnEdit">Edit</button>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

and i tried like this in my jquery

```
$(".btnEdit").on("click", function(){
    alert("clicked");
});
```

but if i clicked the button, the alert never showed up, how to solve my case??

*note : sorry if question like this was discuss before

thanks

Comment: Your code should work fine. The only reasons it wouldn't are 1) You didn't include jQuery properly 2) You are running the code before the DOM has loaded 3) The element is appended after the DOM has loaded, and you're not using a delegated event handler.

Comment: Are you doing this in $(document).ready function? Because you have to make sure that dom is created when you attach event listeners

Comment: just try to, `console.log($(this))` inside the click event, you will get all object of clicked button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a jquery function after dom changed with an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200586/call-a-jquery-function-after-dom-changed-with-an-event)

Comment: Check your console may be there will be any error

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan now the alert showed up according the id, e.g if id is 5, the alert showed up 5 times, if id is 3, the alert showed up 3 times how to fix it ?

Comment: You can get the id from the button using `$(this).prop('id')`. You can put that in a `for` loop and show the `alert()` as many times as needed - although that behaviour sounds really annoying.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan my code like this : `$(".thumbnail").on("click", "#delete", function(){ alert($(this).data('id'));});`

Comment: why is this code different from the one in your question? is this a different question? if so, please ask a new question. if no, please edit your question, and put this code in there, and add more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">       
        <button class="btn btn-success btnEdit">Edit</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script>

$(".btnEdit").on("click", function(){
    alert("clicked");
});
</script>
```

The alert works fine.Have you added jquery plugins to your code?

Comment: He might have missed to add the plugin. BTW I do not have enough scores to add a comment. :) That's why posted it as an answer.

Comment: i think if i don't use foreach() my code work fine because i just use 1 button, but i'm using foreach which is mean the thumbnail and button will more than 1

Comment: You meant to say that you have more than one button?

Answer (score 0):

Have you included jquery? Try to wrap it using $(document).ready(function(){})

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".btnEdit").on("click", function(){
     alert("clicked");
   });
 });
```

Comment: You can open the console (developer tools) and check for the clues.

Comment: pls do not say i'm not loaded the jquery... i know the basic to use jquery

Comment: @DarkCode999 well you haven't shown that, so we don't know. Please update your question with a more complete example of the problem. Also, answering some of the comments on the question would help clear up the confusion here, as what you've shown would work when used correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for headline question: 
*How to detect which button is clicked in jQuery*

```
<tr><td>...<button class="btn btn-success btnEdit">Edit</button>...</td></tr>
<tr><td>...<button class="btn btn-success btnEdit">Edit</button>...</td></tr>
<tr><td>...<button class="btn btn-success btnEdit">Edit</button>...</td></tr>


$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btnEdit").on("click", function(){
    var $button = $(this);


  });
});
```

Can be used for handling listed parts (rows ...)